# Creating maven custom plugin

Tags: maven, plugins

I have created a custom plugin in Maven. However, the `jar` file that is created has the name `CustomPlugin-1.0.jar.lastUpdated` 'lastUpdated' is the extension, and it's not possible to open the file due to it being corrupt.

The steps I followed to create it are as follows:

- First I created a maven plugin using maven (created a maven project with `packaging=maven-plugin`).
- Then I put a class in there that extends `AbstractMojo` and contains the custom plugin code.
- Then I built it with maven. Maven created the corrupt jar as mentioned above.

How do I create a valid jar file for a custom plugin?

Comment: Post a simplified version of your Mojo and of your pom.xml. Maven does not create `lastUpdated` file in a project, only in your repo.

Comment: Why have you created a custom plugin ? What is the intention? Not solvable by other existing plugins?

Answer (score 0):

Use maven-shade plugin to package your jar. It will automatically package and create a jar(fat-jar) with all the dependencies, resources and correct jar name and extension.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0</version>
  <configuration>
    <!-- put your configurations here -->
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>shade</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Add this to your custom maven plugin pom and the build using `mvn clean install`.